# org-babel result to a separate buffer

Tags: org-mode, buffers, org-babel, window, performance

I use org-babel to generate some reports which can't be automatically processed, and since org is a good outline format, I print the results in org to represent them as trees.

I've noticed that nesting org markup into `#+begin_example` block makes emacs really slow (and the formatting of the results is off, too).

It would be really cool to have babel place the output of certain code blocks to a separate buffer (and open a window for it too), the same way as it handles errors.

I've looked through documentation but it seems like there's no such option.

Am I wrong? If I'm not, maybe someone has such a snippet around?

Also, the slowness might be caused by some other options in my configuration, how's your experience with org formatted text nested into `example`? Maybe I'm barking under the wrong tree here.

Thanks

Comment: I should add that these are not huge or complicated reports. It's several hundred lines, two-three levels deep, under a hundred nodes overall. My actual org files are way bigger. Once I remove ``#+begin_example`` they work just fine

Comment: I was able to create this new feature without too much trouble, but `org-mode` is always evolving and `org-babel-insert-result` is already rather quite long, and it will be even longer with this modification.  **Step #1**:  Decide on a new RESULT-PARAMS like the word `separate`.  The source-code block can contain something like `:results output separate`  **Step #2**:  Turn the `if/then` statement that contains the condition `(and result-params (member "silent" result-params))` into three conditions with the new one being `(and result-params (member "separate" result-params))` and set new buf.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I've looked through documentation but it seems like there's no such option.

Surprising that `org` does not offer `:output buffer` option. Maybe this is in the works for future `org` versions.

> ... place the output of certain code blocks to a separate buffer...

Here's one way to simulate that functionality: take the output of one source block and `stream` it into a `new buffer`:

```
#+NAME: mycontent
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value :results raw :exports results
(print "this content is streamed to a new buffer")
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: mystream
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var c=mycontent :results none
(prin1 c (generate-new-buffer "new"))
#+END_SRC
```

Because `mycontent` source block feeds the content to `mystream`, you will have to execute only the `mystream` src block. That is, `C-c C-c` on `mystream` block.

If you `C-c C-c` on the `mycontent` src block, then the results will be inserted in the same buffer.

Although `mycontent` is shown as an emacs-lisp src block, this can be any valid org src block. You may have to adjust the `:results` options based on the language.

The `:results none` for the `mystream` src block is counter-intuitive, but the magic that gets your content into a new buffer.

Answer (score 5):

Since I've accepted the answer I've been living with that 'have elisp snippet for each report I want' setup for a while.

But then I've came up with the following trick:

There *is* a way to open org-babel outpupt in a separate buffer with `C-o` - `org-open-at-point` is fancy like that. The problem is, the result block is created. But there is also a command `org-babel-remove-result`. Combining the two, I made a little dirty hack

```
(defun my-babel-to-buffer ()
  "A function to efficiently feed babel code block result to a separate buffer"
  (interactive)
  (org-open-at-point)
  (org-babel-remove-result)
)

(defun my-org-mode-config ()
  "To use with `org-mode-hook'"
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-`") 'my-babel-to-buffer)
)

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-config)
```

The codeblocks I use like that have properties `:results output :format raw :exports results`

My file with tips and howtos is no longer cluttered with large outputs and the buffer is reused (which suits my workflow).

Comment: If you want this behavior all the time, you can use your custom command as a hook: `(add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'my-bable-to-buffer)))`.

Comment: No, just in some cases, to grab a report of puppet failures or something like that.